# Alternative way to handle state in React using memo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

When it comes to handling complex state in React everybody suggests to flatten the state to avoid something like this just to update a single property:

```js
setState({ …state, user:{ …state.user, profile:{…state.user.profile, address:{…state.user.profile.address, city:’Newyork’}} }});
```

Which is really cubersome to work with. There is another way: use an object holding your state and return that from a memoized function. Then whenever you made a change simply force a re-render.

```js
// note the reference cannot be changed, but values can.
const data = useMemo(() => ({
    user: {
        name: "",
        profile: {
        address: {
            city: "New york"
        }
        }
    }
}), []);

// use dummy data to trigger an update
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

function forceUpdate() {
    setToggle(prev => !prev);
}

function makeChanges() {
    // make any change on data without any copying.
    data.user.address.city = "new city name";
    // hydrate the changes to the view when you're done
    forceUpdate();
}

return (
    <div onClick={() => makeChanges()}>{data.user.address.city }</div>
)
```

Which works perfectly. Even with massive and complex data structures.

From what I can tell state is really just a memoized values which will trigger an update upon change.

So, my one question: What is the downside of using this?

Comment: You might want to consider [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), which is recommended for managing complex states such as yours

Comment: I have to ask: Does your `forceUpdate` function actually cause anything that depends on `data` to re-render?

Comment: Agree, using useReducer is suited for complex states. But the real question is what is wrong with direct state manipulation for a manual render trigger?

Comment: The only downside I see that matters, and it's a big one, an anti-pattern in React in fact, is that you are mutating the state object. ***Don't mutate React state***. This shouldn't, and likely wouldn't, pass any code review process. `forceUpdate` functions are also anti-pattern and generally a code smell.

Comment: @DrewReese But OP _*wants to mutate React state*_ and is asking if it's wrong and what could happen if they do that because they _*really wanna*_.

Comment: @AKX Then I suppose OP learns the hard way how to React. ‍♂️

Comment: @DrewReese That's what I'm thinking, too. 

Comment: _what is wrong with direct state manipulation for a manual render trigger?_ Well for one, this is not how react works. Secondly, the state manipulation functions provided by `useState` or `useReducer` are the main gateways for changing state in react, i.e. making react actually react. If you want to know if react notices the updates you did to `data`, then you need to pass data to something else as a prop or use it as a dependency in a useEffect, and see if anything happens as a result of directly changing state like you did

Answer (score 0):

[The docs say](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) `useMemo` is not a guarantee:

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.** In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values [...]

If you'd *really* want to do something like this and you are absolutely positively sure you're  willing to do things unlike anyone else in React land, you'd use `useRef` for state storage that doesn't cause rerenders by itself. I'm not going to add an example of that, because I don't recommend it in the least.

You should also note that your method will not cause memoized (`React.memo()`) components to rerender, since they will not "see" changes to props if their identity does not change. Similarly, if another component uses one of your internally mutated objects as a dependency for e.g. an effect, those effects will not fire. Finding bugs caused by that will be spectacularly annoying.

If modifying deep object structures is otherwise cumbersome, see e.g. [the Immer library](https://github.com/immerjs/immer), which does [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) magic internally to let you modify deep objects without trouble – or maybe [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) if you're feeling more old-school.

Comment: Valid. But what about useState instead of useMemo and use as suggested? What is the real issue with direct state manipulation with a manual update trigger?

Comment: React.memo's 2nd parameter allows for a custom equality check

Comment: Can you pinky-swear that all of the components, even those from external libraries, you use work just fine with direct state manipulation (i.e. they all have custom equality checks with `memo`s, don't use mutable objects as dependencies to their internal hooks...)?

Comment: And by "proxy magic" you mean that *it* (*the immutability utility*) handles all the shallow copying for you automagically so new object references are returned and React's reconciliation process functions as expected.